# android webrtc VideoCapturerAndroid crashing due to applicationContext not set

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I am implementing calling feature using webrtc. I successfully able to make voice calls. But video call providing error. Even I could not add the local stream through VideoCapturerAndroid. I searched all the references found by googling but none of them worked for my case. I changed the media constraints(video) according to supporting formats, but no luck. Please help me to solve the problem.

It is showing runtime exception **applicationContext not set.**

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext not set.
W/System.err:     at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid.startCapture(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:499)
```

Full log is given below.

```
04-12 15:08:03.657 23560-24939/com.example.messenger D/VideoCapturerAndroid: VideoCapturerAndroid
04-12 15:08:03.657 23560-24939/com.example.messenger D/VideoCapturerAndroid: init: Camera 1, Facing front, Orientation 270
04-12 15:08:03.657 23560-24939/com.example.messenger D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Get supported formats.
04-12 15:08:03.657 23560-24939/com.example.messenger D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Opening camera 1
04-12 15:08:03.842 23560-23560/com.example.messenger V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{152a65d3 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1d90e60a {com.example.messenger/com.example.messenger.activity.ChatActivity}} show : false
04-12 15:08:04.007 23560-24939/com.example.messenger D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Opening camera 0
04-12 15:08:04.192 23560-24939/com.example.messenger D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Get supported formats done.
04-12 15:08:04.197 23560-24939/com.example.messenger D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Supported formats for camera 1: [
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 1920,
                                                                                              "height": 1080,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 1440,
                                                                                              "height": 1080,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 1280,
                                                                                              "height": 960,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 1280,
                                                                                              "height": 720,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 1056,
                                                                                              "height": 864,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 1024,
                                                                                              "height": 768,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 1008,
                                                                                              "height": 566,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 800,
                                                                                              "height": 600,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 800,
                                                                                              "height": 480,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 800,
                                                                                              "height": 450,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 720,
                                                                                              "height": 480,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 640,
                                                                                              "height": 480,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 528,
                                                                                              "height": 432,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 480,
                                                                                              "height": 320,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 480,
                                                                                              "height": 270,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 352,
                                                                                              "height": 288,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "width": 320,
                                                                                              "height": 240,
                                                                                              "framerate": 30
                                                                                            }
                                                                                          ]
04-12 15:08:04.202 23560-24946/com.example.messenger D/VideoCapturerAndroid: startCapture requested: 640x480@30
04-12 15:08:04.202 23560-24946/com.example.messenger W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext not set.
04-12 15:08:04.202 23560-24946/com.example.messenger W/System.err:     at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid.startCapture(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:499)
04-12 15:08:04.202 23560-24946/com.example.messenger E/rtc: #
                                                                         # Fatal error in ../../talk/app/webrtc/java/jni/androidvideocapturer_jni.cc, line 126
                                                                         # Check failed: !jni()->ExceptionCheck()
                                                                         # error during VideoCapturerAndroid.startCapture
                                                                         #
04-12 15:08:04.202 23560-24946/com.example.messenger A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 24946 (Thread-64952)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide the code snippet you are using, it's easy to find the issue.

Below are steps to generate local video track from camera.

```
private VideoCapturer createCameraCapturer(CameraEnumerator enumerator) {
   final String[] deviceNames = enumerator.getDeviceNames();
   // First, try to find front facing camera
   Log.d(TAG, "Looking for front facing cameras.");
   for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
     if (enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Creating front facing camera capturer.");
       VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);
       if (videoCapturer != null) {
         return videoCapturer;
       }
     }
   }
   // Front facing camera not found, try something else
   Log.d(TAG, "Looking for other cameras.");
   for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
     if (!enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Creating other camera capturer.");
       VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);
       if (videoCapturer != null) {
         return videoCapturer;
       }
     }
   }
   return null;
 }

 VideoCapturer videoCapturer = createCameraCapturer(new Camera1Enumerator(captureToTexture()));
 VideoSource videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer);
 videoCapturer.startCapture(1200/*width*/, 720/*height*/, 25/*fps*/);

VideoTrack localVideoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack("NameYourTrack", videoSource);
```

Below code is to render the local video

```
EglBase rootEglBase = EglBase.create(); 
SurfaceViewRenderer pipRenderer = (SurfaceViewRenderer) findViewById(R.id.pip_video_view); //You need define your UI element to render video 
pipRenderer.init(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
pipRenderer.setScalingType(ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT);
localVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
localVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(pipRenderer));
```

**Note:** This code will work with latest WebRTC code base, if you are using old native library, you may need to update OR look for corresponding AppRTCMobile example.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me the version of WebRTC you are using. Current I am using 'io.pristine:libjingle:9694@aar' for android.

Comment: pristine .aar is years old, you can build latest by following instructions @ https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/ on Ubuntu machine

Comment: I uploaded my frameworks in the following git repo https://github.com/AjayChoudary/WebRTCFramework/

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+archive/master/webrtc/examples/androidapp.tar.gz